# How to appear short text in p tags html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am new MVC So I am creating a small blog by myself , I have a long text but i want to display only a short text if i click on the "More" this link it will appear those text that is being hide.Like those people have a very long comment, Facebook will appear a short text and it use the "More" link to display the rest of the text

[image]

And Here is paragraph that I expect :

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: What is your question and where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you exactly want, but from what I inferred is you want to toggle to show less/all text. For this there are few js plugins which can be incorporated with your application.

Comment: Yes that I want . Could you please share me some js plugins. Thanks.